# Scraping ajax call with form data not in JSON format

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have limited Python experience, and am trying to scrape to scrape a website which makes use of ajax calls. I have tried to follow the examples provided on different websites, but I haven't succeeded yet, most likely due to that the form data of my ajax calls isn't formatted as JSON.

The ajax call in this case has form data in the following format:

```
filters[targetValueMin]: 0
filters[targetValueMax]: 15000000
filters[interestRateMin]: 0
filters[interestRateMax]: 20
filters[loanTermMin]: 0
filters[loanTermMax]: 240
filters[platforms]: 
filters[financingTypes]: 
filters[developmentPhases]: 
filters[investmentPurposes]:
```

Therefore my question is: How can I scrape the content coming from this ajax call?

The ajax call can be recreated by going to https://www.crowdfundmarkt.nl/crowdfundingprojecten and adjusting one of the filters on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Make a POST request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#make-a-post-request) in request documentation to send form-url-encoded data. Then parse the json result :

```
import requests
payload = {
    'filters[routeName]' : 'projects_list', 
    'filters[pageNr]' : '1',
    'filters[funded]' : '1',
    'filters[targetValueMin]' : '0',
    'filters[targetValueMax]' : '15000000',
    'filters[interestRateMin]' : '0',
    'filters[interestRateMax]' : '20',
    'filters[loanTermMin]' : '0',
    'filters[loanTermMax]' : '240',
    'filters[platforms]' : '',
    'filters[financingTypes]' : '',
    'filters[developmentPhases]' : '',
    'filters[investmentPurposes]' : '',
    'filters[businessEntities]' : '',
    'filters[states]' : '',
    'filters[sectors]' : '',
    'filters[search]' : ''
}
r = requests.post("https://www.crowdfundmarkt.nl/crowdfundingprojecten/ajax-fetch", data=payload)
print r.json()
```